# Jmeter select xmltype oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, select, jmeter, clob

I want to extract xml data stored in XMLDATA column using JMeter
my table FINAL_XML has following columns

```
IDENTIFIERTYPE | IDENTIFIER | DATE      | XMLDATA
-------------- | ---------- | --------- | -------
CONTACT        | 1          |0216-08-04 | CLOB, 4500 Bytes
```

following select is returning correct result (just to be sure if i configured Jmeter correctly):

```
Select XMLDATA from FINAL_XML
where identifier = 1
```

but if i want to see xml content and run

```
select xmltype(XMLDATA) from FINAL_XML
where identifier = 1
```

i receive error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xdb.XMLType
```

is there a way to use xmltype select using jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

That class is in the xdb6.jar package, which you can get from [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) and put in your class path (in addition to ojdbc6.jar, which I guess you already have). They should be compatible version too.